# Trying to use a class but get a NoneType error with Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I´m trying to build my first game using Python and Kivy. I have used Kivy:s Pong Game Tutorial as an base for my game https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/pong.html and I did get my ship (png-file) move on a background. Then I followed Sentex guide on buttons https://youtu.be/CYNWK2GpwgA and tried to move my game in to a menu system.

Now my game does not work. I get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center_x' when I try to move my ship.

I have tried to trace back the problem and understand what´s happening. At first I thought the error was because of the ship was an NoneType object but when I use .self. I use the class SpaceGame_TheGame? How can that be a NoneType when I use it in the class it self?

(I´m new to programming and new to the forum, I'm trying my best but I guess both code and post looks like crap to you ppl...)

Thankful for any help!

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty #Want my ship to be an object (right?)
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition #For menu system
from kivy.lang import Builder



#The different screens
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
class SpaceGame(Screen):
    pass
class Installningar(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


# The game
class SpaceShip(Widget): #The ship is a class
    pass


class SpaceGame_TheGame(Widget):
    player = ObjectProperty(None) #I want the ship to be an object that can get hit and stuff

    def on_touch_move(self,touch): #For movement
       pass
       self.player.center_x = touch.x
       self.player.center_y = touch.y


#Start up stuff
presentation = Builder.load_file("space.kv") #Presentation är bara ett namn på detta som han valde
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

```
#: kivy 1.10.1
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import Window kivy.core.window


ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    SpaceGame:
    Installningar:

<Button>:
    font_size: 20
    color: 0,1,0,1
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.15

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "spacegame"
        text: "Start the game!"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, 'center_y':0.7}

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "installningar"
        text: "Settings"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, 'center_y':0.5}

    Button:
        on_release: quit()
        text: "Quit"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, 'center_y':0.3}


<SpaceShip>:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: 45,45
            pos: self.pos
            source: 'rymdskepp.png'


<SpaceGame>:
    name: "spacegame"
    player: space_ship

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'bakgrund.jpg'


    FloatLayout:
        SpaceShip:
            id: space_ship
            x: root.x
            center_y: root.center_y


        SpaceGame_TheGame
            id: spacegame_thegame # an id for referring to this widget

        Button:
            text: "Back"
            pos_hint: {"right": 1, 'top':1}
            on_release: app.root.current = "main"


<Installningar>:
    name: "installningar"


    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Back"
            pos_hint: {"right": 1, 'top':1}
            on_release: app.root.current = "main"
```

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\fredr\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-06-13_28.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 388.13'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 980 Ti/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/fredr/OneDrive - Nyköpings Enskilda Gymnasium/Matematik/Programmering/Blandat/Kivy/Mitt spel 2/main.py", line 42, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 826, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 502, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 727, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 460, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 340, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 325, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 231, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1362, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_move', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1388, in on_touch_move
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_move', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1196, in on_touch_move
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_move(touch)
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 471, in on_touch_move
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_move', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 296, in on_touch_move
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_move(touch)
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 471, in on_touch_move
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_move', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\fredr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 471, in on_touch_move
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_move', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:/Users/fredr/OneDrive - Nyköpings Enskilda Gymnasium/Matematik/Programmering/Blandat/Kivy/Mitt spel 2/main.py", line 29, in on_touch_move
     self.player.center_x = touch.x
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center_x'

Process finished with exit code 1

I want my ship to move and don't get the error message...
```

Comment: At a quick glance, you never set `SpaceGame_TheGame` to something other than None. You have ` player: space_ship` in your kv for the `SpaceGame` class, but that's a different widget.

Comment: You literally say self.player = ObjectProperty(None) in your code

Comment: How could I references it different to make it work? How can I change it from None to something? :) 

The self.player = ObjectProperty(None) part is used in the pong game on kivy.org guide. Dont know why that game works...

Answer (score 0):

## Problem - AttributeError

```
     self.player.center_x = touch.x
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center_x'
```

## Root Cause

`player` is defined as an [ObjectProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ObjectProperty) and initialized to `None` inside the class `SpaceGame_TheGame(Widget)`. This property is ***NOT*** updated to hold the instance of the `SpaceShip` referenced by the `id: space_ship`.

Therefore, when your app tried to retrieve `center_x` via `player`, it threw an error i.e. `NoneType` object.

### Note

*In your Kivy app, there are two unique [ObjectProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ObjectProperty) with the name, `player`. One is declared in class `SpaceGame_TheGame(Widget)`. The other one is automatically created by Kivy and added to the `Screen` widget, `SpaceGame`* because the widget doesn’t have a property with that given name, `player`.

## Solution

### kv file

- Move `player: space_ship` from class rule, `<SpaceGame>:` to under instantiated object, `SpaceGame_TheGame:`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<SpaceGame>:
    name: "spacegame"

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'bakgrund.jpg'
    ...

        SpaceGame_TheGame:
            id: spacegame_thegame # an id for referring to this widget
            player: space_ship
```

### py file

- In `on_touch_move()` method, replace `self.player.center_x = touch.x` and `self.player.center_y = touch.y` with `self.player.pos = touch.pos`

#### Snippets - py file

```
class SpaceGame_TheGame(Widget):
    player = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        self.player.pos = touch.pos
```

### Output

[image: Result - moved spaceship]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)